# How to get "check in" informations with Facebook Place id?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

According to Facebook Graph API documentation, it is possible to get detailed informations about users check in. You need an access token and "user_checkin" permissions (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/checkin/).

> https://graph.facebook.com/user_id/checkins

I would like to get the same informations from a "Facebook Place" point of view. I can get the number of check in with :

> https://graph.facebook.com/place_id/checkins

But I can't find a way to get an array with detailed informations (who, when, likes connection, comments connection).

I didn't find anything about that in documentation. Do you have any idea how I could achieve that ? Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Chekins use the following Graph API :

For getting friends Checkins:

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(authenticatedFacebook.request(""+id+"/checkins"));
```

where **id is friend id** , and **authenticatedFacebook is Facebook object**

For getting Recent checkins of Logged user :

```
JSONObject  jObject4= new JSONObject(authenticatedFacebook.request("search?type=checkin&access_token=token"));
```

where **access_token is your Valid access token**

For getting Checkins of Logged User :

```
JSONObject  jObject1 = new JSONObject(authenticatedFacebook.request("me/checkins"));
```

Comment: With those methods you only get checkins from specific user of friends of specific user.
What if you want the list of checkin for a specific place ?

Comment: @Julien G. You can get the nearest place, and it's not possible to get checkins for specific location.

Comment: so there is no way to know who check in your place or store ? It would have been useful...

Comment: But i think you can get only your friends list who checkins for specific place.